# C++ timestamp and diffTime

Tags: c++, time, timestamp, time-t

I'm trying to know the timestamp when I receive a message.
I should check if it has been N seconds of receiving the last message.
I'm using `time_t`.
I take the current time like this: `time (& myTime);`

how can I check if they spent more than N seconds?

Is there a way to know the number of seconds (timestamp) of a total time_t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask the "number of seconds" of a `time_t`. This would be *absolute time*. You'd want probably then want to format it using `localtime()` or some such function in hour/minute/second, day/month/year form.

If you want to know the time *since a previous event*, you should simply save the `time_t` from that event and then use a statement like `if (difftime(thisevent_time, lastevent_time) > max_seconds)` to handle it.